# Java pyramid program print numbers?

Tags: java

How to write a java program to print below the pattern?

```
     0
    1 2
   3 4 5
  6 7 8 9
```

I tried this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++) {
    for (int s = levels; s > i; s--) {
        // add spacing
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        // display/add star
        System.out.print(i+j+" ");
    }
    // add new line
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: This isn't a website to have code written for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: use a for loop with mod conditions to introduce newline

Comment: Oh.. please.. not that pyramid again..

Comment: @Dragondraikk reputation can be also  built solely on popular, well-received questions (unlike this one, IMHO). Even if someone is not that good at programming, he may still have interesting questions.

Comment: @vefthym Yes, but one would assume that having built up reputation over the course of two years, a user would build some understanding of what sort of questions works here and what does not.

Comment: Great, you added code. What's the problem with the code? You haven't described any particular issue, are we meant to guess or debug it for you? -1, voted to close.

Comment: @Dragondraikk that's true. I just replied on how this user has built his/her reputation. And that's 4 years, by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make a small modification.i declared a variable `int z = 0;` each time it print a character increment `z` by one.because this pattern goes like `0,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,++++.......`

```
int levels = 4;
int z = 0; // this make it easy
for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++) {
    for (int s = levels; s > i; s--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {

        System.out.print(z + " ");
        z++;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

the output

```
    0 
   1 2 
  3 4 5 
 6 7 8 9
```